# Force between two parallel plates with water between them

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, surface-tension

Find the force required to separate two plates with water between them water wets the plates and area of contact of water with each plate is A.
Distance between the two plates is 't'.(Surface tension of water: 'S')

I have tried the problem by pressure difference approach but I am getting the answer as
$$
\frac{4 s A}{t}
$$ but the answer is given as $$
\frac{2 s A}{t}
$$
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The force required is equal to negative the pressure force exerted by the water. Assuming that the the water makes a 0 degree contact at the plate (so there is no vertical component of the surface tension force acting on the plate)
by Young-Laplace
$$\Delta P= { S}({1\over R_1} + {1\over R_2}) $$
This helps us find the pressure of the water.

We can take $R_1$ to be the radius of curvature of the water along the vertical axis, and $R_2$ to be the radius of curvature along the horizontal axis. Now, assuming the water doesn't curve as you move sideways, and assuming the water curves inwards in a perfect circle at the edges, after finding $R_1$ and $R_2$, the force can be calculated from $F=(\Delta P)A$

Answer (score 0):

I think you considered the fluid between the plates to be spherical, but the space between the two plates is cylindrical.